# Verify and show that the following is a distribution and prove if it is a tempered distribution

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I've been struggling to verify and show that  the following function is a distribution and whether its a tempered distribution.

Let $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ for $x \in \mathbf{R}$.

Really do appreciate the help and any insight on how to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Should possibly be $\sqrt{|x|}$ in the denominator? Otherwise you will have problems with negative $x$.

Comment: @md2perpe thanks for pointing that out, I just changed it!

Answer (score 0):

1. A locally integrable function induces a distribution. $|x|^{-1/2}$ is locally integrable.
2. Multiplication of a distribution with a smooth ($C^\infty$) function gives a distribution. $\cos x$ is a smooth function.
3. A distribution that doesn't grow too quickly at infinity is a tempered distribution. $|x|^{-1/2} \cos x$ doesn't grow at all at infinity.

Comment: Hey! I wanted to know if this would then have compact support? or how to determine that? thank you for answering! :)